# Where do you recommend an experienced developer learn Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to learn some Javascript **before** jumping into a framework like jQuery or Moo Tools.

Since I'm already familiar with C#/Java/Python, I'd like a resource that just shows me how to do things and not waste time with, this is an object, here's how you add numbers, etc.

What resource would you recommend for me? Thank you very much.

Comment: +1 for the first sentence alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748/) (although you should note that while it is a very good guide to the language, it doesn't talk about DOM)

Comment: The most valuable thing I got from this was that good developers often jump into javascript figuring, "I know Java (or C#, etc), so I can do javascript."  But with that approach you may miss much of the good stuff about javascript.

Comment: DOM is one of the bad parts :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think www.w3schools.com is useful, at least as a reference

Comment: W3Schools is half-baked at the best of times. If you want a reference, then the MDC JavaScript reference and the W3C DOM specifications are much better.

Answer (score 0):

Object-Oriented JavaScript is a good book for learning JavaScript if you're already familiar with something else. It explains JavaScript core concepts but also has more advanced items like how OOP works in JS, which is something that can be confusing at first when coming from languages like C# or Java.

Mozilla Developer Central's JavaScript site is an excellent reference for looking up built-in JavaScript functions, such as what methods array have and even more obscure things like XPath support. https://developer.mozilla.org/En/JavaScript